# Проблема с загрузками ресурсов в JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, spring-mvc

У меня в папке `webapp` есть другая папка - `static` (**webapp/static**). В этой папке у меня лежат ресурсы: изображения, скрипты, каскадные стили.

Пытаюсь загрузить картинку на JSP страничку. Внутри тега *body* прописываю следующее:

```
<img src="/static/images/schedule-map.png" id='image'/>
```

Сама идея показывает мне, что видит эту png-картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо этого всего, у меня настроен конфиг маппинга:

```
<!-- Step 6: Define resources (css, js) -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/static**" location="/static/"/>
```

Но когда я запускаю Tomcat'ом приложение - я получаю JSP без картинки. Браузер не определяет её, хотя всё равно видит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема?

Comment: должно быть resources/static

Comment: @RomanC но ведь идея находит эту png-шку

Comment: @RomanC или имеете в виду, что оно может быть только в ресурсах?

Comment: тогда надо чтобы сервер переписал URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно быть так:

```
/contextPath/static/images/schedule-map.png
```

где contextPath это:

1. Название папки в котором лежит проект (если деплоите вручну)
2. contextPath указанный в настройках сервера Tomcat (если деплоите через идею).

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте контекст к URL:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/schedule-map.png" id='image'/>
```

Comment: К сожаленнию, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так 
(`img src=" resources/images/1.png" width="200" height="200"`)